# configure: yocto error: GNU Fortran is not working (libgfortran)

Tags: fortran, yocto, gfortran

I would like to build **glibfortran** by x86_64-poky-linux. However, it generated the error as below:

```
| checking whether the x86_64-poky-linux-gcc  -m64 -march=nehalem -mtune=generic -mfpmath=sse -msse4.2  -Wdate-time --sysroot=/home/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc-runtime/10.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot linker (x86_64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc-runtime/10.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot   -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
| checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... (cached) no
| checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
| checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
| checking for shl_load... (cached) no
| checking for shl_load in -ldld... (cached) no
| checking for dlopen... (cached) yes
| checking whether a program can dlopen itself... (cached) cross
| checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
| checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
| checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
| checking whether to build static libraries... yes
| checking for x86_64-poky-linux-gfortran... (cached) no
| checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... (cached) no
| checking whether no accepts -g... (cached) no
| checking whether the GNU Fortran compiler is working... no
| configure: error: GNU Fortran is not working; please report a bug in http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla, attaching /home/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/gcc-runtime/10.2.0-r0/gcc-10.2.0/build.x86_64-poky-linux.x86_64-poky-linux/x86_64-poky-linux/libgfortran/config.log
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/build/../meta-x/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_10.2.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
```

Some Yocto configs were followed the instruction at: https://jumpnowtek.com/yocto/Add-Fortran-support-to-a-Yocto-build.html.

Anybody experienced on this error? Thanks!

```
GNU Fortran is not working; please report a bug in http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla
```

Comment: Any update on this? Looks like I'm having exactly same issue with aarch64

Comment: I had success by not having the bbappend for gcc-runtime as mentioned in the jumpnowtek article you gave a link to.